# branch de github no git

Tags: git, github, branch

Eu fiz um fork de um projeto que estou fazendo em grupo, no Github pelas abas de branch eu fiz 3 branch novas, no meu repositório local no sistema operacional Windows 10 eu digito o comando git branch para visualizar os ramos e os ramos do Github não estão no repositório local, então fiz o comando git pull origin main para atualizar o repositório local e ele parece estar atualizado mas do mesmo modo não conseguir acessar as branch que existem no github no git, não ficou claro o que devo fazer preciso criar as branch pelo git no repositório local? eu desejo ter as mesmas branch do Github no git. Desde já agradeço pelas respostas.

Comment: Supondo que você tenha uma branch `feature-a` no repositório remoto e tentar ir para ela no seu repositório local com `git checkout feature-a`, você não consegue?

Comment: Não consigo Rafael, não consigo entender porque isso parece que as branchs que criei só existem no github, inclusive eu nomeei elas pelo tipo de desenvolvimento que vou fazer, um banco-de-dados, outra com php e a ultima com bootstrap, e reparei que você deu um nome de recurso, aproveitando isso devo fazer uma branch para um recurso ao invés de todo um desenvolvimento de diversos recursos em uma linguagem?

Comment: Estranho, a branch remota geralmente não aparece mesmo com `git branch` mas você pode dar um `git checkout` após o `git pull`. Sobre o outro assunto, o nome e processo para criação de branch é baseado em opinião e varia de acordo com o time que está trabalhando no projeto, com o tempo você pode aperfeiçoar isso para suas necessidades caso perceba que a ideia inicial não ficou legal, não pense demais sobre isso - você pode mudar de ideia a qualquer momento.

Comment: * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date. ele aparece isso quando faço o comando git pull origin main

Comment: Estou usando o comando git branch para tentar ver as branchs não sei se esse comando é o correto para esse propósito.

Answer (score 0):

Se continuar tendo esse erro tente criar a branch local e aí vc sobe pro github.

```
git checkout -b nome-da-sua-branch
```

*Com esse comando você cria e já dá checkout.*

```
git push --set-upstream origin nome-da-sua-branch
```

*E com esse comando vc sobe a branch pro github.*

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).